# htaccess how to make folders public

Tags: apache

I got two folder in the root

```
agentPhoto/
tradingcard/
.htacess
```

I want to make those folder public accessible. my current rules are like this. How can I add the `tradingcard` folder to the rule ?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/agentPhoto
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /agentPhoto/$1 [L]


#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|font|js|photo|db|robots\.txt)
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```